# Sorting Array of objects with multiple criterias

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is my array:

```
let a = [
    {
        IsGroup: true,
        Name: "Antonia Doyle"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: false,
        Name: "Dana Gray"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: false,
        Name: "Amber Banks"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: false,
        Name: "Geoff Neal"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: true,
        Name: "Nina Hartley"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: false,
        Name: "Elizabeth Warren"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: false,
        Name: "Ghengis Khan"
    },
    {
        IsGroup: true,
        Name: "Masta Razz"
    }
];
```

I can't see to sort it by `IsGroup` and then `Name`. However, it doesn't seem to be working. My code so far:

```
let b = [];
b = a;

b.sort(byGroupThenName);

function byGroupThenName(a, b) {
    return b.IsGroup - a.IsGroup || (a.Name - b.Name ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: So you want to group your array by isGroup field and then sort the groups. is my understanding right?

Comment: FYI Subtracting two non-numeric strings (!) always produces `NaN`, regardless of the values of the non-numeric strings.

Comment: Subtracting strings does not make sense. It should be `a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name)`, which will give the exact kind of result you need for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) can be used to compare strings :

```js
let arr = [ { IsGroup: true , Name: "Antonia Doyle" },
          { IsGroup: false, Name: "Dana Gray" },
          { IsGroup: false, Name: "Amber Banks" },
          { IsGroup: false, Name: "Geoff Neal" },
          { IsGroup: true , Name: "Nina Hartley" },
          { IsGroup: false, Name: "Elizabeth Warren" },
          { IsGroup: false, Name: "Ghengis Khan" },
          { IsGroup: true , Name: "Masta Razz" } ]
    
arr.sort((a, b) => b.IsGroup - a.IsGroup || a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name))

console.log( JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dynamicSort()` function which takes two params `property` and `order` (`asc` & `desc`)

```js
let a = [ { IsGroup: true , Name: "Antonia Doyle" },
      { IsGroup: false, Name: "Dana Gray" },
      { IsGroup: false, Name: "Amber Banks" },
      { IsGroup: false, Name: "Geoff Neal" },
      { IsGroup: true , Name: "Nina Hartley" },
      { IsGroup: false, Name: "Elizabeth Warren" },
      { IsGroup: false, Name: "Ghengis Khan" },
      { IsGroup: true , Name: "Masta Razz" } ]

const dynamicSort = (property, order) => {
  let sortOrder = 1
  if (order === 'desc') {
    sortOrder = -1
  }
  return function(a, b) {
    // a should come before b in the sorted order
    if (a[property] < b[property]) {
      return -1 * sortOrder
      // a should come after b in the sorted order
    } else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
      return 1 * sortOrder
      // a and b are the same
    } else {
      return 0 * sortOrder
    }
  }
}

const sortedArr = a.sort(dynamicSort('IsGroup','desc'))

console.log(sortedArr)
```

Comment: But we cannot pass another property(ie Name)?

Comment: you can pass any property to it

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase, can I pass more then one property to it?

Comment: No, just one prop

Comment: In this case, I'm going to mark Slai's answer as the correct answer(it is my main requirement). However, +1 for a great suggestion. Thank you.